# Change iPhone DatePicker "blue today date"

Tags: iphone, datepicker

I want to know if it's possible to changed programmatically the blue todays date without delete and reload the date picker ?

[image: iPhone DatePicker]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to be sure !
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date animated:(BOOL)animated
```

method.

e.g.

```
[myDatePicker setDate:someNSDate animated:YES];
```

It's the only instance method of the UIDatePickerClass (see [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) for more details).

Comment: Thank you for your response !
But your solutions permit me only to change the "selected" date, not to change the today's date highlighted in blue.